# How to add date range in woocommerce with code

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using Woocommerce and Woocommerce bookings plugins and I would like to add Date Range with time throught a custom code.

[image]

I want to add :

- **Date from => to**
- **Time from => to**
- **Bookable** : Yes

I know how to add a lot of other fields like price, name, description etc ... ex.

```
add_post_meta( $product_ID, '_wc_booking_has_persons', 'yes' );
```

but I can't figure out how to do it for the Range because it's dynamic and needs a click of button... Any help is much appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figure out how to do it with a bit of reverse engineering, hopefuly this helps someone :

```
    $availability = array();
    $availability[0]['type'] = 'time:range';
    $availability[0]['bookable'] = 'yes';
    //Default priority
    $availability[0]['priority'] = 10;

    //case 'time:range'
    $availability[0]['from'] = wc_booking_sanitize_time( $hours );
    $availability[0]['to']   = wc_booking_sanitize_time( $hours );
    $availability[0]['from_date'] = wc_clean( $date );
    $availability[0]['to_date']   = wc_clean( $date );

    add_post_meta( $product_ID, '_wc_booking_availability', $availability );
```